# Getting the last fillled column in a sheet1 and copying the data in sheet2 to sheet1

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets.

sheet1 and sheet2.

I have my data in sheet2. The sheet1 already contains data until 4th row.

I would like to copy all the data in sheet2, from row5 to sheet 1 after the 4th row.

I tried the below code. but each time I run the code. it is getting copied randomly in 114 row or sometimes in 1000th row.

here is the code , I am using to copy.

```
Sub FClookup()
Dim LastRow As Long

    'get last row
    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5:W1000").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LastRow + 1)


End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of LastRow? Perhaps there are cells which look empty but have hidden contents?

Comment: @SJR it shows 1048576

Comment: That is the very last row of a spreadsheet so therein lies your problem. I would Clear the contents of the whole column and then run the macro.

Comment: @SJR I will try your solution as well :)

Comment: @SJR I completely deleted the sheet and used another sheet , and had the same macro and it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you're looking for. The code is assuming that Column A in Sheet2 is always filled and will copy all the data from Columns A to D from Sheet2 to the next free Row in Sheet1 (checking column A).

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyStuff()

    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    ws2.Range("A5:D" & ws2.Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
    ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlValues

End Sub
```